# I can't detach a listener on firestore using polymer

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, polymer-2.x

I'm developing an app in polymer using Firestore.
Everything works well, except that i can't detach listeners from the database.
I've prepared same code so that anyone can try it.

```
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer-element.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/paper-fab/paper-fab.html">
<dom-module id="test-app">
<template>
    <style>
         :host {
            display: block;
        }
    </style>

    <h2>connect</h2>
    <paper-fab on-tap="connect"></paper-fab>

    <h2>change something</h2>
    <paper-fab on-tap="changeSomething"></paper-fab>

    <h2>disconnect</h2>
    <paper-fab on-tap="disconnect"></paper-fab>

</template>

<script>
    class TestApp extends Polymer.Element {
        static get is() {
            return 'test-app';
        }
        static get properties() {
            return {
                text: {
                    type: String
                }
            };
        }
        getRef() {
            return db.collection('utenti').doc('ZLpc0IDlkEVeb9DEKR2f')
        }
        connect() {
            console.log('connect');
            this.getRef().onSnapshot((doc) => {
                console.log('text Changed');
                console.log(doc.data());
                this.text = doc.data().titolo
            });
        }

        changeSomething() {
            let newText = this.text + ' randomtext'
            this.getRef().update({
                titolo: newText
            })
        }

        disconnect() {
            console.log('disconnect');
            var unsubscribe = this.getRef().onSnapshot(function () {});
            unsubscribe();
        }


    }

    window.customElements.define(TestApp.is, TestApp);
</script>
```

in the example above i have 3 buttons,
pressing the first one will correctly connect to the document

```
log 
1 connect
2 text Changed
3 [object]
```

than i press the second to make same change

```
log 
4 text Changed
5 [object]
```

than i press the third to disconnect

```
log
6 disconnect
```

and at this point i press the second to check that the disconnection really happened and i get

```
log
7 text Changed
8 [object]
```

at this point is clear that the disconnection never really happened.
the disconnection code is right out of the firestore documentation, so that can't be the problem.

version of all the software should be updated (firebase from bower, polymer cli from yarn, last version of chrome)

firestore offline persistence was never enabled

this can get to be a pretty expensive problem... can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Based on my tests, you need to keep track of your initial query and later call unsubscribe on that. When you introduce

```
 var unsubscribe = this.getRef().onSnapshot(function () {});
```

unsubscribe() acts on that as a new query to detach listener on and won't remove the one you intended to detach. So save your query in a variable and later detach either manually or via observer like below. Keep in mind if your query changes, the previous listener is still listening and need to be detached (in observer of _handler for example).

```
...
<script>
    class TestApp extends Polymer.Element {
        static get is() {
            return 'test-app';
        }
        static get properties() {
            return {
                text: {
                    type: String
                }, 
                //handler to save query for later removal
                _handler: {
                    type: Object,
                    observer: '_onHandlerChange',
                    value: function(){
                       return {}
                    },
                },
            };
        }

         //save query into _handler
        connect() {
            this._handler = this.getRef().onSnapshot((doc) => {
                console.log('text Changed');
                console.log(doc.data());
                this.text = doc.data().titolo
            });
        }

        //detach by accessing your initial query here
        disconnect() {
            var unsubscribe = this._handler;
            unsubscribe();
        }

        //or you could keep removing old query if your query changes like this
        _handlerChanged: function(newH,oldH) {
            console.log(`_handlerChanged` , newH , oldH);
            if (!oldH) return ; 
            const unsubscribe = oldH;
            unsubscribe();
        },

    window.customElements.define(TestApp.is, TestApp);
</script>
```